# Why does the TAP::Harness Perl module have a "NotBuild.PL" file?

Tags: perl, tap

The TAP::Harness 3.23 tarball includes a NotBuild.PL file (and no Build.PL file), but the README specifically states:

To use Module::Build (preferred) do:

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
./Build test
./Build install
```

Is this just an oversight or is there some reason to avoid using Module::Build? Is this how Build.PL files are normally distributed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/AndyA/Test-Harness/commit/7b68accc195e159fab1412ca07a8715583e68c75) will answer your question:

From the Github:

> History for Test-Harness
>
> April 13, 2010
>
> **Rename Build.PL to NotBuild.PL to avoid pulling in Module::Build as a
>   dependency for people who've told CPAN.pm to prefer MB over EUMM.**
>
> This is so a recent version of T::H can become a dependency of Test::Simple without Module::Build becoming (effectively) a transitive dependency of Test::Simple.